# Change part color/line of graph in subplots based on difference t and t+1

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following dataframe.

```
data = {'Year': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], 'Paris': [1020, 20200, 2000, 6000], 'Tokyo': [102000, 320000, 402000, 100]}
sales=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
sales=sales.set_index('Year')
fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), tight_layout=True, sharex='all')
sales.plot(ax=a, subplots=True, rot=90,color='grey',linewidth=1, linestyle='dashed')
```

which results to these graphs

[image]

How can i change it so i can get the last part of the graph in another colour and thickness:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this showld made the job

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Year': [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021], 'Paris': [1020, 20200, 2000, 6000], 'Tokyo': [102000, 320000, 402000, 100]}
sales=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
sales=sales.set_index('Year')
fig, a = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), tight_layout=True, sharex='all')
axs = sales.plot(ax=a, subplots=True, rot=90,color='grey',linewidth=1, linestyle='dashed')
axs[0].plot(sales[sales.index >= 2020].index,sales[sales.index >= 2020]['Paris'], color="g", linewidth=3, linestyle='dashed')
axs[1].plot(sales[sales.index >= 2020].index,sales[sales.index >= 2020]['Tokyo'], color="r", linewidth=3, linestyle='dashed')
plt.show()
```

[image]